# How can I code an IronPython Silverlight application entirely in python, and what are the minimal necessary components in the HTML?

Tags: html, silverlight, ironpython

I've been banging my head against to wall for weeks to put together the minimal HTML for an IronPython Silverlight application that uses Gestalt, as pioneered by Jimmy Schementi here: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/dynamic-languages/dynamic-languages-in-silverlight and here: http://ironpython.net/browser/gettingstarted.html

But I'm having a hard time loading an application that does anything. Every time I put into the examples any script of my own, the Silverlight application either fails to load, or shows nothing in its object. I want to have the HTML foundation so that I can begin accessing the Silverlight libraries and start coding/testing graphics for my app. (But I can't get there yet.)

Taking from his examples, I've put together the following HTML, which calls my visual.py - a python file that should be able to do everything that a XAML file does by accessing the Silverlight libraries.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body { height: 100%; overflow: auto; }
    body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
    #silverlightControlHost { height: 90%; text-align: center; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.DLR = {settings: {windowless: 'true'}}
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gestalt.ironpython.net/dlr-latest.js"></script>
  <title>webcam-mic</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="application/python" src="visual.py" id="python" width="100%" height="100%""></script>

</body>
</html>
```

But this doesn't work. The .py file it calls has: (also taken from working IronPython examples from elsewhere)

```
from System.Windows import Application, Thickness
from System.Windows.Controls import (
    Button, Orientation, TextBlock,
    StackPanel, TextBox
)
from System.Windows.Input import Key

root = StackPanel(Width=500,Height=500)
textblock = TextBlock()
textblock.Margin = Thickness(20)
textblock.FontSize = 18
textblock.Text = 'Stuff goes here'
root.Children.Add(textblock)

panel = StackPanel()
panel.Margin = Thickness(20)
panel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal

button = Button()
button.Content = 'Push Me'
button.FontSize = 18
button.Margin = Thickness(10)

textbox = TextBox()
textbox.Text = "Type stuff here..."
textbox.FontSize = 18
textbox.Margin = Thickness(10)
textbox.Width = 200
#textbox.Watermark = 'Type Something Here'

def onClick(s, e):
    textblock.Text = textbox.Text
    textbox.Text = ""

def onKeyDown(sender, e):
    if e.Key == Key.Enter:
        e.Handled = True
        onClick(None, None)

button.Click += onClick
textbox.KeyDown += onKeyDown

panel.Children.Add(button)
panel.Children.Add(textbox)

root.Children.Add(panel)
Application.Current.RootVisual = root
```

What additional components do I need? (Is the problem with the version of dlr.js? My script tags? Version of Silverlight?) All I need is the necessary code to produce a full screen Silverlight app that takes all of its controls and graphics from a python file. So far, nothing I've put together has worked. I'm running Firefox with Silverlight 4.0.

Comment: When you say 'this doesn't work', what do you mean?  Does the Silverlight plugin crash or fail to load?  Do you get an error message and/or a stack trace?  Does the same thing happen in other browsers?

Comment: Start with the template in `IronPython-2.7\Silverlight\script` and adjust it step by step towards your image.

Comment: By fail, I mean that either the applet fails to load on the HTML page, or the applet loads, but its contents are blank, as if I did not have Silverlight code in there at all.

Comment: Lukas, this template where you mentioned requires the use of Chiron and .xap'ing the folder with the app.py file. I think using Gestalt would be much simpler, but both are not working for me. I've looked up numerous tutorials around the internet, but I have issues with making any of them work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lukas Cenovsky's suggestion and the tips from [here](http://www.typeoneerror.com/articles/post/silverlight-development-on-mac-osx-my-first-app): , I used the sdl-sdk to create a template much like the template in `IronPython-2.7\Silverlight\script` and created a .xap file with Chiron and Mono. I thought that Gestalt would obviate the need for using Chiron to create a .xap, but whatever works. Thanks, all!

For future reference, the Terminal command to create a .xap is something like: `mono /path/to/Chiron.exe /d:directory_with_pyfile /z:name.xap`

Answer (score 0):

How are you serving the HTML file? Any HTML file with  references must be served from a web-server, not the file-system, so no file:// URLs.

You can also use Chiron to produce your own .xap file. Then the XAP file can be served from any web-server you want, but if you want any reasonable dev experience you'll have to use "Chiron.exe /w" as your web-server.

Comment: I was serving it on a university server for my domain (and accessing with www). I did mistakenly try serving it from my own filesystem, but the results were the same - if the applet did load they were blank. Last night, I managed to get Chiron working to produce .xap files for my server and serve it while dev'ing, so all's reasonably well.

Comment: Shame the first option didn't work for you; it's how all the examples on http://ironpython.net/browser/examples/ work (eg. http://ironpython.net/browser/examples/mushroom/ and http://ironpython.net/browser/examples/mandelbrot/). But using a .xap file is more Silverlighty, while using <script type="text/python"> is a clever ploy to convince you the web (and JavaScript) are better options than Silverlight.